# Does binding order matter when binding multiple operations to a single control event?

Tags: ios, bind, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

When binding two specific operations to a button tap, does execution order follow binding order?

For example, in the following code, is there a way to tell what gets executed first?

```
self.resetButton.rx.tap.bind(to: viewModel!.resetPasswordButtonObserver).disposed(by: disposeBag)

self.resetButton.rx.tap.bind {[weak self] in
    self?.loader.lock()
}.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

In my code, the viewModel calls an API and executes the reset operation before the `self?.loader.lock()` block is executed, which may cause problems for really fast connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you change the thread that the code executes on, it will execute in the order you wrote it.

Comment: So the execution order obeys the binding order unless the operations are being executed concurrently? For some reason I thought all bindings were executed simultaneously. Thanks for your answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: RxSwift is synchronous by default. All work is executed at the moment the subscribe is called.